# How to create a custom api domain name for my rest API using AWS CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, aws-cloudformation, aws-serverless

I have an AWS Serverless cloudformation template creating a lambda function and a rest api. I would like some guidance or pointers on the steps to take in order to create a custom API domain name so that my api have the URL:

api.search.mydomainname.com

How does this work with my existing Serverless function code and the Events?

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31


MyFunction:
...
 Events:
        ProxyResource:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            RestApiId: !Ref RestApi
            Path: /{proxy+}
            Method: ANY
        RootResource:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            RestApiId: !Ref RestApi
            Path: /
            Method: ANY
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a good solution regarding the problem at:

https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/issues/40